# How can I better visualize the path that a value takes through an SSIS Data Flow and the operations that are performed upon it?

Tags: ssis

I find that I regularly need to track a value through an SSIS Data Flow. The process that I use to do this is manual and time consuming. Are there any techniques or tools that I can use to reduce the effort (and potential for error)?

What I really need is a means of quickly identifying the data flow components that modify the values in a specific field and ideally the expressions within which it is referenced. I frequently get questions like 'Where did this value in the database come from?'. I would like to be able to answer with something like the following...

'The origin of this value is this field in this other database. It flows from the source to the destination through this data flow. Along the way, it is incremented here, negated there and concatenated with this other field there.'

Comment: Value as in variable value or value in the dataset coming from your table in the buffer?

Comment: I am referring to a value that is held within the buffer (the intersection of a row and column) as it 'flows' from a source to a destination component in a data flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use what's called a data viewer: [How To Add a Data Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx). It shows you the outputted data that is created after each transformation component.

Comment: Hi rfonn. I do use data viewers but they don't really address the problem that I am trying to describe here. I have expanded the question and I hope that it is now a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a random thought, but as SSIS package files are just xml documents, couldn't you search the document for the fieldname you are interested in and find all the references to it that way?

Comment: Hi HLGEM, that is also something that I have used in the past. In many cases within the XML though, the fields are only referenced using an identifier. Interpreting it all manually can be a lot of work.